# How do I switch in between tabs in my View pager so it loads a specific fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a main activity with 3 buttons. The 3 buttons will take you to Tabbed Activity. The first button takes you to tab 1 which is the default. What code do I need so when I hit button 2 it'll take me to tab 2. Button 3 would take me to tab 3 and so forth. Please don't just say to pass on an extra. I've tried and that crap doesn't work. Would be very grateful for a solid answer, been stuck on this for months.

MainActivity.java

```
 public void TakeToTab (View view) {

    //GOTO defa
    Intent i = new Intent(this, TabbedActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
}

public void TakeToTab2 (View view) {

    //GOTO tab2
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            TabbedActivity.class);

    i.putExtra("Tab2", 2);
    startActivity(i);


}

public void TakeToTab3 (View view) {

 //GOTO tab3
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            TabbedActivity.class);

    i.putExtra("Tab3", 2);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

}

TabbedActivity.java

```
public class TabbedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);

//This right?
    int position1 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Tab1");
    int position2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Tab2");
    int position3 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Tab3");


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

//This right?
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position1);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position2);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position3);
```

Comment: Why do you say putExtra not work? `i.putExtra("fragmentNumber", 1)`, I think it 's correct. In your `TabbedActivity`, you can get position by `int position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("fragmentNumber");` . Set `viewwpager.setCurrentItem(position)`.

Comment: Hello RoShan Shan, thanks for taking the time to reply.  Ok I'm starting to see my errors. I've never set the position. So I set the viewpager position in the OnCreate method right? For button 3 would I just add "i.putExtra("fragmentNumber", 3)" for my third tab?

Comment: Right, you set position in  onCreate method after setting adapter for viewpager. I think Tab 3 should be `"i.putExtra("fragmentNumber", 2)`.

Comment: hey RoShan, I edited the code. Let me know if I'm using the code correctly. For some reason Button 1 and 3 are working. Button 2 will take me to tab 1.

Comment: `//GOTO tab2
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            TabbedActivity.class);

    i.putExtra("Tab2", 1); // It should be 1
    startActivity(i);`